# unusually high memory consumption by the kernel

Tags: memory

I have an issue with some of my VMs. They are used as workstations for our designers, and run Centos 6.10. After a month of use, they seem to run out of memory for some reason.

```
> free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         36148      35734        413          0         25        178
-/+ buffers/cache:      35530        617
Swap:         2304        117       2187
```

There are no big processes running on it, and the amount of cache used is insignificant. After a lot of digging I came accross kernel memory slabs, and specificaly the slabs that cannot be reclaimed (SUnreclaim).

```
> more /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       37015692 kB
MemFree:          427320 kB
Buffers:           26192 kB
Cached:           183376 kB
SwapCached:        10476 kB
Active:            49876 kB
Inactive:         191844 kB
Active(anon):      13464 kB
Inactive(anon):    18892 kB
Active(file):      36412 kB
Inactive(file):   172952 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       2360316 kB
SwapFree:        2240324 kB
Dirty:               100 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         28320 kB
Mapped:            17792 kB
Shmem:               112 kB
Slab:           36030684 kB
SReclaimable:      13704 kB
SUnreclaim:     36016980 kB
KernelStack:        5328 kB
PageTables:        19112 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    20868160 kB
Committed_AS:     808636 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      380368 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359346944 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:        8044 kB
DirectMap2M:    37740544 kB
```

So from the 36G of ram, 34-35G are reseved by the kernel and cannot be reclaimed.

```
> slabtop -o
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 10121078 / 10203079 (99.2%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 4305167 / 4305178 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 117 / 209 (56.0%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 35978633.10K / 35991994.40K (100.0%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.02K / 3.53K / 4096.00K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME                   
4188823 4187702  99%    0.06K  70997       59    283988K size-64                
2694370 2694370 100%    8.00K 2694370        1  21554960K size-8192              
1385644 1385644 100%    2.00K 692822        2   2771288K size-2048              
668261 668261 100%   16.00K 668261        1  10692176K size-16384             
423810 423458  99%    0.25K  28254       15    113016K size-256               
374168 373771  99%    1.00K  93542        4    374168K size-1024              
144400 138675  96%    0.50K  18050        8     72200K size-512               
142080  90740  63%    0.12K   4736       30     18944K size-128               
 26412  26401  99%    4.00K  26412        1    105648K size-4096              
 24864  24000  96%    0.03K    222      112       888K size-32                
 15680  10729  68%    0.19K    784       20      3136K dentry                 
 13949  13949 100%    0.10K    377       37      1508K buffer_head            
 13446  13436  99%    0.14K    498       27      1992K sysfs_dir_cache        
 13360  10073  75%    0.19K    668       20      2672K size-192               
 13015  11061  84%    0.20K    685       19      2740K vm_area_struct         
 11396   7556  66%    0.05K    148       77       592K anon_vma_chain         
  8692   8661  99%    0.07K    164       53       656K selinux_inode_security 
  8308   5456  65%    0.05K    124       67       496K anon_vma               
  6642   6547  98%    0.58K   1107        6      4428K inode_cache            
  5100   3788  74%    0.25K    340       15      1360K filp                   
  4095   3885  94%    0.55K    585        7      2340K radix_tree_node        
  2160   2062  95%    0.98K    540        4      2160K ext4_inode_cache       
  1908   1872  98%    0.07K     36       53       144K Acpi-Operand           
   780    642  82%    0.19K     39       20       156K cred_jar               
   770    748  97%    0.77K    154        5       616K shmem_inode_cache      
   610    547  89%    0.69K    122        5       488K sock_inode_cache       
   552    503  91%    0.04K      6       92        24K Acpi-Namespace         
   510    416  81%    0.12K     17       30        68K pid                    
   476    401  84%    0.11K     14       34        56K task_delay_info        
   462    453  98%    0.53K     66        7       264K idr_layer_cache        
   424    396  93%    0.88K    106        4       424K UNIX                   
   392    360  91%    0.50K     49        8       196K task_xstate            
   354    350  98%    2.61K    118        3       944K task_struct            
   318     92  28%    0.07K      6       53        24K eventpoll_pwq          
   295     62  21%    0.06K      5       59        20K tcp_bind_bucket        
   290    196  67%    0.38K     29       10       116K ip_dst_cache           
   288    209  72%    0.12K      9       32        36K inotify_inode_mark_entry
   259    234  90%    1.06K     37        7       296K signal_cache           
   256    159  62%    0.23K     16       16        64K cfq_queue              
   252    157  62%    0.13K      9       28        36K cfq_io_context         
   240    154  64%    0.08K      5       48        20K blkdev_ioc             
   240     92  38%    0.12K      8       30        32K eventpoll_epi          
   236    232  98%    0.06K      4       59        16K fs_cache               
   225    225 100%    2.06K     75        3       600K sighand_cache          
   208    208 100%   32.12K    208        1     13312K kmem_cache             
   202      2   0%    0.02K      1      202         4K jbd2_revoke_table      
   202      2   0%    0.02K      1      202         4K revoke_table           
   176    146  82%    0.69K     16       11       128K files_cache            
   150    129  86%    1.38K     30        5       240K mm_struct              
   150     99  66%    0.12K      5       30        20K scsi_sense_cache       
   144    102  70%    0.64K     24        6        96K proc_inode_cache       
   144     16  11%    0.02K      1      144         4K fsnotify_event_holder  
   144      6   4%    0.02K      1      144         4K fasync_cache           
   144     17  11%    0.02K      1      144         4K jbd2_journal_handle    
   141     82  58%    1.02K     47        3       188K nfs_inode_cache        
   140    140 100%    0.19K      7       20        28K virtio_scsi_cmd        
   135    108  80%    0.25K      9       15        36K scsi_cmd_cache         
   120    115  95%    0.25K      8       15        32K mnt_cache              
   112      7   6%    0.03K      1      112         4K dnotify_struct         
   112     16  14%    0.03K      1      112         4K inotify_event_private_data
   112      2   1%    0.03K      1      112         4K sd_ext_cdb             
    92     31  33%    0.04K      1       92         4K khugepaged_mm_slot     
    88     80  90%    0.17K      4       22        16K file_lock_cache        
    80     80 100%    0.19K      4       20        16K bio-0                  
    77     64  83%    0.34K      7       11        28K blkdev_requests        
    75     66  88%    0.25K      5       15        20K ndisc_cache            
    74     13  17%    0.10K      2       37         8K ext4_prealloc_space    
    68     68 100%    0.11K      2       34         8K jbd2_journal_head      
    60     60 100%    0.12K      2       30         8K nfs_page               
    59      1   1%    0.06K      1       59         4K inet_peer_cache        
    59     23  38%    0.06K      1       59         4K fib6_nodes             
    53     10  18%    0.07K      1       53         4K ip_fib_hash
```

A simple restart will resolve the issue, but it is disruptive to restart every VMs every month. Any ideas on how to debug this, and find where all this memory is going?

Thanks
Nick

Comment: CentOS 6 is past end of life. It might not be possible for the community to help you. You should upgrade to a currently supported release as soon as possible. (but in no case later than 2020)

Comment: I also added slabtop report.

Comment: We are looking into transitioning to Centos 7, but have some legacy software that still requires 6